# Django crispy forms error message

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am very new to Python and django. And I am currently having an issue I cannot overcome. I have tried reading all the docs and googling, but nothing so far.

I have a very custom login form I need to use. All the code is there are works so far. I just want to authenticate the user (which works fine), but if they enter the incorrect details, I want to show an error message on the form saying invalid login details instead of returning an HttpResponse, but I cannot seem to figure out how exactly to display an auth error like this on a crispy form like this.

Any help would be much appreciated

Oh yes, and this is python 3.4 if that makes any difference

This is my forms.py:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField(
        label="Your email address",
        max_length=80,
        required=True,
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        label="Your password",
        required=True,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'form-login'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-login'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_action = 'login'
        self.helper.field_class = 'form-control input-lg'
        self.helper.form_show_errors = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('email', template='crispy/login_input_email.html'),
            Field('password', template='crispy/login_input_password.html'),
        )

        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('login', 'Log me in', css_class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password',)
```

This is my views.py:

```
def login_view(request, template_name='login.html'):

    redirect_url = request.GET.get('next')

    if request.method=='POST':
        loginForm = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if loginForm.is_valid():

            username = loginForm.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = loginForm.cleaned_data.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if redirect_url is None:
                    redirect_url='/home'

                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
        return render_to_response(template_name, {'crispy_form': loginForm}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        loginForm = UserLoginForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'crispy_form': loginForm}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And lastly, this is my template:

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
   <div class="inner-block">
        <h1>Log in to your account</h1>
        {% crispy crispy_form crispy_form.helper %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the messaging system

```
from django.contrib import messages

...
else:
    messages.error(request, "Your error message")
    loginForm = UserLoginForm()
....
```

Check on the django.contrib.messagges doc.

Comment: Great. This was the solution that ended up working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check and see if you are getting the HTML5 `required` attribute added to the form element tags for the elements that you have defined as required in your `models.py`.

If you are, and required elements are missing from your form, the HTML5 client-side validation in your browser prevents the form submitting, so you don't get a `request.POST` and so no Django server-side validation and thus no `form.errors` are returned.

I spent a good few days puzzling out this one. Anyways, starting with Django 1.10, you can [turn off the HTML5 `required` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.use_required_attribute) in the form elements* and rely on the server-side Django validation (and template error messages).

*In my testing the HTML5 form validation bubble support was hit/miss and I have users in locked down machines who may not have the latest, greatest browser version.